# Update specific Items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I want to update (and delete) specific rows in my ListView knowing the attributes (id and name) of the object contained in the ListView. I don't know the position, therefore I can't use

```
View v = mListView.getChildAt()
```

I'm using an adapter for the List View, which is extending an ArrayAdapter of my model class.

How can I override the method getPosition ?
Here my ListViewAdapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelTimer> {


    public List<ModelTimer> mListOfTimers;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ModelTimer> modelTimerList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_active_timer, modelTimerList);
        this.mListOfTimers = modelTimerList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        ModelTimer modelTimer = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder holder;// view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_active_timer, parent, false);
            holder.tvTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.active_timer_timeLeft);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.active_timer_name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        holder.tvTime.setText(modelTimer.expirationTime);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(modelTimer.name);

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(ModelTimer item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }

    // View lookup cache
    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvTime;
    }


}
```

Comment: Make a listener which commicate between activity and your adaper...

Comment: Could I see any example?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do it, but look this code:

```
 @Override
    public int getPosition(ModelTimer item) {
     int pos = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < mListOfTimers.size(); i++ )
      if(mListOfTimers.name.equals(item.name) // and check id
      pos = i;
        return pos;
    }
```

Comment: Why not the best way?

Comment: because if size of items is too large, this cycle will iterate them in ui thread and it will take some time.